# Is the American Revolutionary War an example of civil disobedience?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I am involved in an argument with a friend about the meaning of *civil disobedience*. The question is whether or not the American Revolution involved civil disobedience. To clarify, this does not refer to the events leading up to the revolution, but the actual fighting. The argument against the use of *civil disobedience* is that it usually refers to nonviolence. The argument for its use is that it does not always have to refer to nonviolence. A source for this view is [this article](http://commons.pacificu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1277&context=eip).

Is it be correct to use *civil disobedience* to refer to the violent parts of the Revolutionary War?

Comment: The notion of "civil disobedience"—in the U.S., anyway—is closely tied to notions of nonviolent opposition and passive resistance. The tendency goes back at least as far as [Henry David Thoreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Disobedience_%28Thoreau%29). On the face of it, of course, violent opposition to the government by private citizens is civil (not military) and disobedient (uncooperative). But violent conduct ([John Brown's raid on Harpers Ferry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Brown's_raid_on_Harpers_Ferry), for example) is usually treated as something else—insurrection, maybe.

Comment: The very paper you cite begins with the sentence: "It is still an open question whether or not Civil Disobedience (CD) has to be completely nonviolent." Academics who study this issue are themselves conflicted, so i'd say you really are not likely to find the answer here. @Sven Yargs BTW, MLKing cites examples of CD as far back as Socrates, Shadrach, Meshach and Abednego, and the Christians sent to the lions in ancient Rome.

Comment: History (and, by inference, the terms used for it) is written by the victors.  The US, if I remember things correctly, won that one.

Comment: This is a matter for political scientists. The concept can exist in any language, and what qualifies for the label or not has nothing to do with English.

Comment: The paper you cite says: "However, I specify that violence must not be aimed at seriously injuring, or even killing, other individuals...... The main claim is that what really is important is that the civil disobedients be willing to accept the punishment following their law-breaking behaviour. By doing so, they demonstrate the conscientiousness of their civilly disobedient action. This also shows that they are aiming for future cooperation with the State, and are expecting the State to be sensitive to their concern for the principles of justice."  From this, the answer to your Q is NO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a history question, not an English question.  The OP should try http://history.stackexchange.com/, and also read my comment under Bea Bonmot's  answer.

Comment: Not a history question, and not a matter of opinion in the close-vote sense here. The question asks whether the term 'civil disobedience' refers to actions characterized as 'violent'. It might earn a general reference close-vote on the grounds that dictionaries favor one or the other ["(in later use) *spec.* refusal to obey the laws, commands, etc., of a government ... as part of an organized, non-violent political protest or campaign", *OED* 2010] were it not the case that (a) the *OED* is not the final word, and (b) specialized resources could provide a definitive answer re contemporary use.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto to all of the above. And I agree that this is more in the realm of philosophy than mere application of terminology.  There's too much context involved here to answer solely from the perspective of language use and definitions of terms.

However, for the sake of reducing a point in your argument to just that, I think the term that needs to be examined is not *civil disobedience* but *revolutionary war*. By the start of the war, the colonists had already established a separate State entity, under which they waged war against another State, in order to wrest control of the economy and territory by killing enough of whoever got in their way. It was not named the *assimilationary action* or the *integrationary intervention* or the *protest for principles*.

The article states:

- "The disobedients do not aim to protest the whole system, or to topple over the existing government: they want to denounce a violation of those principles of justice accepted as fundamental by the whole community. Therefore, while breaking a particular law to protest, they still want to show respect for the legal system as a whole..."

This clearly describes *civil disobedience* as an action or set of actions that cannot be also simultaneously defined using the terms *revolutionary* and *war*. And more to your point, the statement above also clearly contradicts the expression of the actors in that specific Revolutionary War.

Comment: This is a history question, not an English question.  The question is,  would the colonists, or some of the colonies, have accepted a negotiated compromise sometime early in hostilities, a compromise that would have kept them under British rule, but would have given them much of what they asked for before hostilities began.  I don't know the answer to this.  I suspect the answer is no, but they weren't the United States then, they were a bunch of disparate colonies.

Comment: @ab2 It looked to me like the question specified not the events leading up to the war (Boston Massacre and the like) but the actual war itself. And yes, it's a highly historical-contextualized question, but I believe historians are allowed to ask usage questions, just as language users can ask historical questions. Language and history are not as neatly separable as some might think.  But if the question offends the users of this forum it should be removed.

Comment: I'm not offended by the question -- and I just upvoted your answer as useful, which I neglected to do in the rush of the morning.  I just think the question needs history experts more than English experts.  The question is actually a better question than the questioners seem to know, just not answerable by us.

Comment: I like this answer very much as a corrective to the notion that the American Revolution was a continuation of a high-minded campaign of civil disobedience by other means. Theodore Draper wrote a brilliantly nonpolemical book in 1996 called [_A Struggle for Power: The American Revolution_](http://www.nytimes.com/books/97/04/20/nnp/34002.html), which takes as its thesis that the democratic ideals of the founding fathers (about which we hear so much) were far from the center of the conflict, which was pursued on both sides primarily for economic reasons.

Comment: @SvenYargs. Thanks for that resource!  I'm working on a project about the deconial turn in academia - taking a very interdisciplinary approach - and I might find find some useful bits in this piece.